# First experience: Serial Stalker

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

I think I have a problem. Everyone on Stackoverflow is cool. BUT. After 9K points by way of 580+ answers this is the first time I've had it happen to me.

I have looked article's like this: [Dealing with Stalkers and Unwarranted Persecution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64128/dealing-with-stalkers-and-unwarranted-persecution) and [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

I never ask bad questions that show no research effort, are unclear or not useful. I'm pretty upset by this:

[Controls in the same DataGridView column dont render while initializing grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238322/controls-in-the-same-datagridview-column-dont-render-while-initializing-grid)

[Bind dynamically created Textbox array to a string array or List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081418/bind-dynamically-created-textbox-array-to-a-string-array-or-liststring)

Comment: You only got 2 downvotes. Not much of a stalker there, I'm afraid. Are you actually being harassed by comments as well (I don't see any right now, but I guess something could have been there that has since been deleted)?

Comment: What is it you're upset with? Can you be specific?

Comment: I looked at your recent history, but I don't see anything really upsetting there. Is there something specific you want to talk to us about? You can e-mail us directly at `team@stackexchange.com` if you'd rather not post it publicly.

Comment: I have seen quite a few posts from people lately regarding rudeness. Are people getting crankier or more sensitive?

Comment: Wow, only two downvotes? I call that "Thursday". It's frustrating, and it happens, but two downvotes is kind of a non-issue. When you get enough that the system automatically and repeatedly reverses downvotes, then that's a problem.

Comment: Ok I think I am in the wrong...

Comment: @TimPost thanks for that offer Tim, much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, when I read this question and saw that you were asking questions about WinForms, I thought you were being stalked by HighCore telling you incessantly that WinForms sux and that you should be using WPF. I see that *a lot* in the WinForms tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was kind of rude to leave [this as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15538343/1288) (10k only).  That was downvoted along with two other posts a few seconds later.  I doubt it was the OP of that question, as he left a fairly polite comment on your answer over an hour before the downvotes happened.

I'm not judging you for the mild rudeness, I'm just pointing this out because:

1. That should have been a comment.
2. This looks like an isolated incident, and not a case of serial stalking.
3. We get a lot of reports of serial downvoting that could be prevented if people would be nice.

Comment: Also, the OP of that question doesn't have enough rep to downvote. But it's a good point that it's unlikely that someone would just pick someone at random and downvote their posts. Revenge downvoting starts from somewhere.

Comment: @Juhana Ah yes, you're right. They're totally cleared of all charges.  :)

Comment: I see the errors of my ways. Looking at my question there is probably some personal stuff that affecting me atm.

Answer (score 10):

> I never ask bad questions that show no research effort, are unclear or
>   not useful

All that happened here is that someone disagreed with that analysis. Twice.

It isn't the end of the world; take a look at the questions that were downvoted, honestly try to identify and correct any flaws that might have caused the downvotes and move on. It could have been anything from coincidence to someone angrily looking through your profile after you did something to arouse their ire.

If this becomes a serious problem (occurring regularly or with a greater number of downvotes), you can bring this up on Meta and/or flag one of your posts for moderator attention and explain the situation. Do note that there are already measures in place to counteract serial voting, although they don't catch all possible cases.

It is just as easy here to get cheap upvotes as cheap downvotes, so this shouldn't be a significant setback.

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't feel like it: *don't* try to analyze it and ignore it. 2 downvotes could easily be noise.